# Is it bad to put enctype="multipart/form-data" into every form tag

Tags: html, forms, enctype

I am building a small library to help me with form creation, and I am searching for information about the enctype tag.

Is it something that is ok to include in every form or something that should only be used when necessary (i.e. for upload forms)?

Answer (score 2):

`multipart/form-data` will generate a bit more traffic, because it creates both a binary and an ASCII upload.

More traffic means slower response by server. Insignificant slower.

Now it's just a question do you mind that?

Comment: In that case, it won't hurt to be overly zealous with it, cheers

Answer (score 0):

The enctype attribute can be used only if method="post".

Comment: yes, but is it bad to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` into every post form? i.e. a search form, a login form, any form that doesn't have an upload component

Comment: @topherg are you submitting the data or are you using ajax? in ajax really dont care what attributes you have in your form since the configuration of the post is in the ajax form